# image scaling for UITabBar background image

Tags: ios, swift, background, uitabbar

I've created UITabBarController in my application.

Then in `viewDidLoad()` I want to change UITabBar background image. Here is the code I'm trying to make it works:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UITabBar.appearance().translucent = false
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "tabbar_background")
        UITabBar.appearance().contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    }
}
```

But the result isn't correct ([image](http://oi66.tinypic.com/nfny2s.jpg)). Can someone help me to make it fill the entire tabbar frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resizing the `image` to the tab bar size. Or Add an `imageView` to the `tabBar` as `subview`, and then use the image in that `imageView`.

Subclass the `TabBarController` and add `imageview` there:

```
var bgView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tabBarBackground.png"))
bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 60)//you might need to modify this frame to your tabbar frame
self.view.addSubview(bgView)
```

Comment: when place image view to tabbar, it shows above the tabbar buttons and can not see any buttons.

Comment: use view.bringSubviewToFront() on your tabBarItems to make them visible

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem using clipsToBounds.
**Here are my example:**

```
let tabBar = self.tabBar
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

This work perfectly on iPhone X

Comment: `clipsToBounds` helped with my image to clip.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in swift 3

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "gray background"))
    backgroundImage.frame = backgroundImage.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImage)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for a custom translucent tab bar image with custom icons. You will need to refer directly to the tab bar via a variable.

Swift 3

```
private func setupTabBar() {
    print ("Setting up the Tab Bar and Items")

    tabBarView.clipsToBounds = true
    tabBarView.backgroundImage = UIImage()

    let bgView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TabBarBackground"))
    bgView.frame = tabBarView.bounds
    tabBarView.addSubview(bgView)

    tabBarView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.gray
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.gray], for: .selected)

    tabBarLimitsItemView.image      = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TabIconLimits").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBarControlsItemView.image    = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TabIconControls").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBarPayRulesItemView.image    = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TabIconPayRules").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBarSettingsItemView.image    = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "TabIconSettings").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
}
```