# Prevent gradient on UITab bar icons and text in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I am using the following code to apply a gradient on `UITabBarController`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    
    layerGradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 0.06, green: 0.60, blue: 0.55, alpha: 1.00).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0.05, green: 0.09, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00).cgColor]
    layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.0)
    layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.0)
    layerGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
    self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
    self.setUpTabBar()
}
```

It gives me the result (Gradient is applied on images as well):

[image]

What I was expecting:

[image]

How can I prevent gradient to apply over `TabBar` icons?

Comment: Why not use a gradient background image?

Comment: Didn't get you..

Comment: I mean set a gradient background something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/46875014

Answer (score 0):

Set tintColor:

```
tabBar.setTintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
```

Set unselectedItemTintColor:

```
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 95/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 156/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```